# Create Object accessible to all mvc controllers

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an incoming list of headers that I want to put in an object. I want this object accessible to all controllers without having to invoke anything other than calling the object with it's data already populated (like User/Identity works).

I know when doing a custom Identity you can access stuff in Global.asax in Application_PostAuthenticateRequest to have the Identity updated with any custom fields you my have added to your custom Identity.  I can also see the headers there.  So, I could create my object there, which makes my ultimate question: where would be the best place to put that object to make it accessible to the Controllers?

Comment: Does this header information need to persist, or is it being created each time a controller is started? If the latter, you could use dependency injection.

Comment: This data is sent each time from the browser.  It is a browser inside a game (Eve Online to be exact) and every request sends a certain set of headers containing information about the player.